# Loop to match five point differentiation formula

Tags: distributions, procedural-programming

I have a uniform grid (x,y) and I need help to generate a loop to compute (x-2h,y), (x-h,y),(x+h,y),(x+2h,y) for every point of x, and the same thing for every point of y , (x,y-2h),(x,y-h), (x,y+h), (x,y+2h).

```
x = {-0.5`, -0.5`, -0.5`, -0.5`, -0.28700000000000003`,
   -0.28700000000000003`, -0.28700000000000003`, -0.28700000000000003`,
   -0.07400000000000001`, -0.07400000000000001`, -0.07400000000000001`,
   -0.07400000000000001`, 0.139`, 0.139`, 0.139`, 0.139`, 0.352`, 0.352`,
    0.352`, 0.352`, 0.565`, 0.565`, 0.565`, 0.565`};

y = {0.001`, 0.214`, 0.427`, 0.64`, 0.001`, 0.214`, 0.427`, 0.64`, 
    0.001`, 0.214`, 0.427`, 0.64`, 0.001`, 0.214`, 0.427`, 0.64`, 
    0.001`, 0.214`, 0.427`, 0.64`, 0.001`, 0.214`, 0.427`, 0.64`};
```

where h = 0.213;

Thanks.

Comment: Is this to solve a Partial Differential Equation? Can you not just use a standard stencil and convolve it with the original grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want can be easily written as a single `Table`:

```
dx = Table[{{ix - 2*h, iy}, {ix - h, iy}, {ix + h, iy}, {ix + 2*h, iy}}, {ix, x}, {iy, y}]

dy = Table[{{ix, iy - 2*h}, {ix, iy - h}, {ix, iy + h}, {ix, iy + 2*h}}, {ix, x}, {iy, y}]
```

such that the first line reads `dx[[1]][[1]] = {{-0.926, 0.001}, {-0.713, 0.001}, {-0.287, 0.001}, {-0.074, 0.001}}`, which is all the variations for the first `x` (`-0.5`) at a fixed `y` (`0.001`).

---

However, if you are trying to solve a Partial Differential Equation, you can try to use a ready-made stencil which has probably already been derived from the above finite-difference method formulae.

For instance, if you are dealing with a [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator) in 2D, you can convolve your grid of $(x,y)$ points with the following kernel:
$$ \nabla^2 = \left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -4 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right ). $$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I need.